# How to exclude @Configuration class from component-scan in testContext.xml

Tags: java, spring

I have a class AppConfig annotated with @Configuration which is having various bean definitions which includes beans which performs a third party hit from the application. now in my spring integration test cases, I do not want these beans to be initialized. that is where I created an another bean with name TestAppConfig annotated with @Configuration where I have mocked all those beans which performs third party hit. now in my testContext.xml I am adding an exclude filter to context:component-scan where I am specifying the AppConfig package to be excluded. but somehow this AppConfig is being initialized everytime. I have tried proper regex, but still things are not working. if anyone know the cause then please share.

Comment: use `@Profile` or `@Conditional`

Comment: Unfortunately i can not use @Conditional because i am using spring 3.2.16

Comment: Show your config and how you start the app.

Comment: You can use @Order(1) in TestAppConfig class to prefer the test configuration over the other configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After see the comment that you are using spring 3.2, you can see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles) for older version of spring to use @Profile

You can use @Profile annotation to determine which @Bean will be created or not.

Example:

Defined Beans are below

```
@Bean
@Profile("production")
    public DataSource prodDataSource() {
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }

@Bean
@Profile("development")
    public DataSource devDataSource() {
        ...
        return dataSource;
    }
```

> For profile called "development"

1. In app.properties `spring.profiles.active=development`
2. `prodDataSource` will not be called. But `devDataSource` will be called

> For profile called "production"

1. In app.properties `spring.profiles.active=production`
2. `prodDataSource` will not be called. But `devDataSource` will be called

Comment: Using @profile worked for me. here is how i solved my problem. Annotated my testAppConfig with @profile("test") and in it's respective test infrastructure setup added @activeProfiles("test"). and annotated my AppConfig with @profile("!test"). this way when my app boot up, even i did not pass any profile explicitly, it just check that the current profile is not test so picks up the configuration.